# flutter_stripe Android stuck on Stripe.instance.applySettings() function

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to get payment from my application. Everything is working fine on iOS. But on Android, my function stuck on this line:

```
Stripe.publishableKey = pk_key;
await Stripe.instance.applySettings(); // after this line nothings happens.
```

thanks in advance.

Here is my full code:

```
try{
    Stripe.publishableKey = pk_key;
    await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
    var total = cartInfo.getTotal();
    var customerEmail = cartInfo.address!.email;
    var data = {
      'email': customerEmail,
      'amount': (total*100),
    };
    var payment_intent = await postRequest(url, data);
    // widget.onLoading!(false);

    print(payment_intent);
    
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: payment_intent['paymentIntent'],
            merchantDisplayName: 'test',
            customerId: payment_intent['customer'],
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: payment_intent['ephemeralKey'],
            merchantCountryCode: 'UAE',
        )
    );

    setState((){});
    await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
}
```

EDIT:
I updated FlutterActivity to FlutterFragmentActivity in main kotlin file. But now undefined method: cotext error raised. I dont understant why? here is the full kotlin code.
https://pastecode.io/s/z86216b1

Comment: Can you check if it returns any errors?

Comment: I have checked console but unfortunately nothing prints. When I remove
```
await Stripe.instance.applySettings(); 
```
this line, my code continues but doesn't show payment sheet

Comment: That makes sense because it doesnt await the result. Since this line is in your main.dart init function what makes you think the code stucks at this line? As long as it presents the Screen it should work.

Can you confirm your main.dart looks similar to this?:
  Stripe.publishableKey = StripeService.publishableKey;
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'merchant.flutter.stripe.test';
  Stripe.urlScheme = 'flutterstripe';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Comment: When I put this line in my main.dart await Stripe.instance.applySettings(); my app doesnt even work. I put my full code.

Comment: Ok I understand. Can you try wrapping it in a try/catch block with printing the error and also confirm your function look like described in the package

Comment: error was I had to update FlutterActivity to FlutterFragmentActivity. Actually I have tried this, but it rise an error "Unresolved reference: context". here is my kotlin code:
https://pastecode.io/s/z86216b1